# How have logged in user's email using oauth in PHP

Tags: php, yahoo-oauth

I used yahoo oauth in my website. In code below that I found on github, for example `$user -> query -> results -> profile -> givenName` returns the first name of logged in user, `$user -> query -> results -> profile -> familyName` and so on.
I searched a lot but still I don't know how to get user's email address.

This is my code :

```
require('include/http.php');
require('include/oauth_client.php');

$client = new oauth_client_class;
$client->debug = false;
$client->debug_http = true;
$client->server = 'Yahoo';
$client->redirect_uri = 'http://www.example.com';

$client->client_id = '';
$application_line = __LINE__;
$client->client_secret = '';


if(($success = $client->Initialize()))
{
if(($success = $client->Process()))
{
    if(strlen($client->access_token))
    {
        $success = $client->CallAPI(
            'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql',
            'GET', array(
            'q'=>'select * from social.profile where guid=me',
            'format'=>'json'
        ), array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $user);
    }
}
$success = $client->Finalize($success);
}
    if($client->exit)
exit;
if(strlen($client->authorization_error))
{
$client->error = $client->authorization_error;
$success = false;
}
if($success)
{
    $yahname =$user->query->results->profile->givenName.$user->query->results->profile->familyName;

echo '<pre>', HtmlSpecialChars(print_r($user, 1)), '</pre>';
}
else
{
echo HtmlSpecialChars($client->error);
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that the profile contains the users email address (it is not listed in the [Yahoo profile docs](https://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/extended-profile-resource.html)). If you have requested the `sdpp-w` scope the the [id token](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0-27.html#id_token) you get when [exchanging an authorization code for an access token](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/flows_authcode/#step-4-exchange-authorization-code-for-access-token) contains the email address of the user under the key `email`.